# My Account not visible in User Accounts

Tags: lightdm, users

I am currently set to automatically log into this machine and I would like to change that. However, when I go to User Accounts, I am no longer listed.

`lightdm/users.conf` file is as such:

```
[UserAccounts]
minimum-uid=500
hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess
hidden-shells=/bin/false /usr/sbin/nologin
```

My current UID is 503, username is none of the listed `hidden-users`, and my shell is `/bin/bash`.

Running Ubuntu 13.04 with Unity on a Dell Optiplex 3010.

Also, `greeter-show-manual-login=true` had to be put in lightdm.conf so that I could log in because my account does not show up on the greeter either.

[image: no account under My Account]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Castis' answer did not quite fix the issue for me, even after a full restart, on Ubuntu 16.04. After editing `/etc/login.defs` to change UID_MIN and GID_MIN from 1000 to 500, I could use `adduser` to create new accounts with low UIDs, but my old account (with UID 502) was still not being shown.

It seems that AccountsService was caching the fact that it *once* thought this was a system account. To fix this, I had to manually edit:
`/var/lib/AccountsService/users/<username>`.

In the `[User]` section, I had to change 
`SystemAccount=true` to `SystemAccount=false`

After restarting the AccountsService daemon (`sudo service accounts-daemon restart`) my username reappeared in the System Settings->User Accounts GUI.

Notably, this was an account that was carried over from a previous install of 14.04, and had had its uid manually changed.

Comment: Castis' answer was not enough for me neither. Tom's solution fixed my Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was unaware that there was an account manager running. I solved this issue by editing `/etc/login.defs`, changing `UID_MIN` from 1000 to 500, and restarting.

You could probably get by just `sudo service lightdm restart` but I restarted the machine as I was also performing a distribution upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

In my case for some reasons my account disappeared from the User Accounts GUI. Checking the answers above I managed to do the following steps:

1. From terminal I changed directory: `cd /var/lib/AccountsService/users/`
2. Then I opened up my account there (check it with `ls`) with nano: `sudo nano <username>`
3. Then I changed the `SystemAccount` property to the opposite value (like from `false` to `true`).
4. Saved it and opened up again and changed the `SystemAccount` value back to it's original.
5. Restarted User Accounts GUI --> Woala it's working again.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  If I understand it well, you followed the indications of previous answers and it worked.  In such a case, it is far better to upvote (once you have enough reputation) the best answer.  It promotes that answer and prevents future users from reading more or less the same content.